# Restore Instance of Analysis Service

Tags: sql-server, ssas

I downloaded

1. adventure-works-multidimensional-model-full-database-backup.zip
2. adventure-works-tabular-model-1200-full-database-backup.zip

from [GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/sql-server-samples/releases/tag/adventureworks-analysis-services)

I would like to restore this in SQL Management Studio Analysis Services, but to do this, I need to create an instance

According to [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/instances/install-windows/install-analysis-services?view=sql-server-2017) I installed

1. MS SQL Server Management Studio
2. MS SQL Server Data Tools

How do I create Analysis Service Instance to log into so I can restore `adventure-works-tabular-model-1200-full-database-backup > 
Adventure Works Internet Sales Tabular Sample Database >
Adventure Works Internet Sales Database.abf`

[image]

Comment: _SQL Management Studio_ is a _client_. You need to install the _server_ software to restore the BAK into. https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/sql-server/sql-server-downloads

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid This totally makes sense!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to download and install SQL Server Developer Edition. Here's the [Download Page](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-downloads) and the direct download [link](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=853016).

Then run the installer to install an Analysis Services Tabular instance on your dev machine.  You can run the installer again to also create an Analysis Services Multi-Dimensional instance, if you need that too.

Comment: Thank you so much ..... I was tinkering with this and figured it out (only difference is I went ahead and installed the entire SQL Server 2016 evaluation version, LOLz). I'm relieved it working now! Once instance per different type of Analysis Service.